# Ckeditor did not work for me?

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter, ckeditor

I want use ckeditor 4.3.4 to codeigniter 2.1.4 i tried to start testing it in jsbin, it did not work.what do i do?

How can you use ckeditor 4.3.4 in codeigniter 2.1.4?
How can install ckeditor basic?

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/lacekiyu/1/edit

Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
<script src="www.ckeditor.com/apps/ckeditor/4.3.4/ckeditor.js"></script>
            <script>
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
                This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
            </textarea>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: open your console -> CKEDITOR is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1). Change your ckeditor js link to correct url: `http://ckeditor.com/apps/ckeditor/4.3.4/ckeditor.js`.
2). Add body onload event, and it will work.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="http://ckeditor.com/apps/ckeditor/4.3.4/ckeditor.js"></script>
  <script>
    function init() {  
      CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
    }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="init()">
    <form>
      <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
        This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
      </textarea>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can you use it codeigniter 2.1.4?How can install ckeditor basic?

Comment: Just add the script tag as shown above, and it will work. You can download ckeditor.js from that link and serve from your server.

Comment: When you download ckeditor, there will be option to choose 'Basic' option. Check this link: http://ckeditor.com/download

Comment: I know and it was downloaded. I do not know how to use files downloaded in html code?

Comment: Once you download files it will be in zip format. Unzip it and copy the ckeditor.js file to your server, where you have placed your html (as asked in the question). In your html, properly reference that js file using `<script src="ckeditor.js"></script>` (I am assuming your html and js files are in same folder on server). I hope this helps.

Comment: In CodeIgniter the view files are stored in `application/views`, by default this is protected by `.htaccess`, so if one tried to reference a JavaScript file placed in this directory, it'd be forbidden. In CodeIgniter assets are commonly stored in the web root.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct the reference to the *CKEditor* script and add the CSS class `ckeditor` to the `textarea`.

```
<head>
  <script src="http://ckeditor.com/apps/ckeditor/4.3.4/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor">
            This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
        </textarea>
    </form>
</body>
```

You could host the CKEditor JavaScript on your server. Assuming it is stored in a folder in your web root, called `assets` (e.g. `public_html/assets`) and the URL helper is loaded, you can reference it in a view:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url("assets/ckeeditor.js"); ?>"></script>
```

Comment: How can you use it codeigniter 2.1.4?How can install ckeditor basic?

Comment: Just add the relevant code above to a view. You could host the CKEditor JavaScript on your server and update the reference to it accordingly.